# Returning Index of inserted rows in a multiple row insert query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I am trying to insert multi row (about 1k) with one Insert SQL query in PostgresSQL 11.2. something like this:

```
insert into foo(id) values(6),(5),(4),(3),(2) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id;
```

it return id of inserted row that is nice. but it will be great for me if get index (started from 0) of inserted rows.

For example consider inserting 5 row with conflict in rows with id 5 and 3 (index 1 and 3) goal is something like this:

```
indexes
------------
0
2
4
```

any idea? its important to me to do this with only one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can return a value that is not in the destination table.  But assuming the values are unique, you can calculate this using `join`:

```
with v as (
      select v.*
      from (values(0, 6), (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2)
           ) v(idx, id)
     ),
     i as (
       insert into foo(id)
          select id
          from v
          on conflict do nothing
          returning id
     )
select v.*
from v join
     i
     on v.id = i.id;
```

Comment: your answer with combination of @Jim solution ( using row_number ) work well.

Comment: @A.F.N . . . Ironically, I was going to put an auto-generation of "idx" in the solution.  However, I didn't think it was reasonable to assume a particular ordering of the values -- and you seem to care about the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it is not possible to return a value that does not exist in the table you're inserting.

Perhaps a combination of [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) and the window function [`row_number`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) can do the trick:

Test data

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (5),(3);
```

Query

```
WITH k AS (
  WITH j AS (
    VALUES (6),(5),(4),(3),(2)  -- here you place your 1k entries!
  ) SELECT column1,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY 1)-1 AS idx FROM j
), l AS (
  INSERT INTO foo SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM k
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id)
SELECT idx FROM l
JOIN k ON k.column1 = l.id ORDER BY idx;

 idx 
-----
   0
   2
   4
(3 Zeilen)
```